# RestEasy With Vert.x authentication Filter

Tags: java, resteasy, vert.x

We've started a new web server with Vert.x and i want to use it with the RestEasy plugin so it will feel a bit more  like API controller.

I want to Authenticate and authorize users via `ContainerRequestFilter` and `RedisClient`.

The issue of-course is the the async model of vert.x and the redis request is async and the `ContainerRequestFilter` will not wait for the async method to end in order to check if the user is authorized or not.

Have anyone found a solution?